# How to open new tab at the end of tab bar in new Opera

Tags: opera

How can I open new tabs at the end instead of next to my current active tab?

Like in Opera 12.

Comment: https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/classic-tabs/?display=en&reports

Comment: The _new_ new Opera is called... [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com/) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the extenion [SimpleTabOrder](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/simpletaborder/?display=en) and select the option `position far right end of all tabs`

[image]